# what is wrong with this json array code facebook form

Tags: arrays, facebook, json, forms

The error i am getting is this : **Can't parse fields attribute. Is it a JSON array or CSV list?**

The problem is in the select menu which is being included in the form. what i want to achieve is a select box as shown here on this link : [Registration plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/)

But somehow the problem is that the select box is not being displayed!

```
<iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
                    client_id=325340244194060&
                    redirect_uri=http://www.pingcampus.com/facebook_registration_plugin/store_user_data.php&
                    fields=[
                    {"name":"name"},
                    {"name":"email"},
                    {"name":"gender"},
                    {"name":"birthday"},

                    {'name':'captain',    'description':'Best Captain',             'type':'select',    'options':{'P':'Jean-Luc Picard','K':'James T. Kirk'}}


                    {'name':'captain',    'description':'College','type':'select','options':


                    {'P':'Jean-Luc Picard','K':'James T. Kirk',                                         
                    '1':'Acropolis','2':'Astral','3':'Aurobindo','4':'BM','5':'Central','6':'Chameli','7':'IET (DAVV)','8':'IIST
     ','9':'IIST2
     ','10':'IPS
     ','11':'JDCT
     ','12':'KCB
     ','13':'LKCT
     ','14':'LNCT
     ','15':'MIT (Malwa)
     ','16':'Malwa (Malwa2)
     ','17':'Mandsaur
     ','18':'Mathuradevi
     ','19':'MITM (Medi1)
     ','20':'MIST (Medi2)
     ','21':'MGIEM
     ','22':'Nalin
     ','23':'Oriental
     ','24':'Patel
     ','25':'Prestige
     ','26':'Priyatam
     ','27':'Rishiraj
     ','28':'RKDF
     ','29':'Royal
     ','30':'Sanghvi
     ','31':'Sdbansal
     ','32':'SGSITS
     ','33':'SIMS
     ','34':'SKSITS
     ','35':'Star
     ','36':'SVCE
     ','37':'SVITS
     ','38':'Transnational
     ','39':'Truba
     ','40':'Venkateshwar
     ','41':'Vidhyasagar
     ','42':'Vikrant
     ','43':'Vindhya
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','#':'Commerce
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','44':'Acro
     ','45':'Apex
     ','46':'Arihant
     ','47':'BM
     ','48':'Chamelidevi
     ','49':'Chimc
     ','50':'Choithram
     ','51':'Christian
     ','52':'DCBS (Daly College)
     ','53':'IBMR
     ','54':'IIMR (IIST)
     ','55':'IIPS (DAVV)
     ','56':'Ilva
     ','57':'IMIR
     ','58':'Imperial
     ','59':'IMS (DAVV)
     ','60':'Islamia
     ','61':'JDCT
     ','62':'LKCT
     ','63':'LNCT
     ','64':'Maharaja
     ','65':'MIT (Malwa)
     ','66':'Mathuradevi
     ','67':'Matushri
     ','68':'MBKhalsa
     ','69':'Medicaps
     ','70':'Patel
     ','71':'Pioneer
     ','72':'Prestige
     ','73':'Priyatam
     ','74':'Renaissance
     ','75':'Rishiraj
     ','76':'Sahib
     ','77':'SAIMS
     ','78':'Sanghvi Innovative
     ','79':'Sapient
     ','80':'SGSITS
     ','81':'SIMS
     ','82':'SJDM
     ','83':'SKSITS
     ','84':'Softvision
     ','85':'SVCE
     ','86':'Rransnational
     ','87':'Vaishnav
     ','88':'Venkteshwar
     ','89':'Vidhyasagar
     ','90':'Vikrant
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','#':'Pharmacy
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','91':'Acropolis
     ','92':'Aurobindo
     ','93':'BM
     ','94':'Central
     ','95':'SOPE (DAVV)
     ','96':'IIP(IIST)
     ','97':'IPS
     ','98':'Oriental
     ','99':'Rishiraj
     ','100':'RKDF
     ','101':'Safe
     ','102':'SGSITS
     ','103':'Smriti (SCOPE) 
     ','104':'svce
     ','105':'vikrant
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','#':'Medical
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','106':'Arihant
     ','107':'Bombay Hospital
     ','108':'Index
     ','109':'MGMMC
     ','110':'RD Memorial
     ','111':'Shubhdeep
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','#':'Dental
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','112':'Aurobindo
     ','113':'CDSH
     ','114':'GCD
     ','115':'Index
     ','116':'Modern
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','#':'Arts
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','117':'BIG Aims
     ','118':'Frameboxx
     ','119':'INIFD
     ','120':'MAAC
     ','121':'SDPS
     ','122':'SJMC (DAVV)
     ','123':'Virtual Voyage
     ','124':'Zica
     ','132':'EMRC (DAVV) 
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','#':'Architecture
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','125':'IPS
     ','126':'SDPS
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','#':'Law
     ','#':'--------------------------------
     ','127':'Christian
     ','128':'SOL(DAVV)
     ','129':'IIL
     ','130':'Vaishnav'}       },

                    {"name":"Arts","description":"Arts","type":"checkbox","value":"Arts"},
                    {"name":"Act","description":"Act","type":"checkbox","value":"Act"},
                    {"name":"Cooking","description":"Cooking","type":"checkbox","value":"Cooking"},
                    {"name":"Dance","description":"Dance","type":"checkbox","value":"Dance"},
                    {"name":"Designing","description":"Designing","type":"checkbox","value":"Designing"},
                    {"name":"Fashion","description":"Fashion Designing","type":"checkbox","value":"Fashion Designing"},
                    {"name":"Interior","description":"Interior Designing","type":"checkbox","value":"Interior Designing"},
                    {"name":"Modeling","description":"Modeling","type":"checkbox","value":"Modeling"},
                    {"name":"Photography","description":"Photography","type":"checkbox","value":"Photography"},
                    {"name":"Poetry","description":"Poetry / Writing","type":"checkbox","value":"Poetry / Writing"},
                    {"name":"Programming","description":"Programming","type":"checkbox","value":"Programming"},
                    {"name":"Reading","description":"Reading","type":"checkbox","value":"Reading"},
                    {"name":"Sketching","description":"Sketching / Drawing","type":"checkbox","value":"Sketching / Drawing"},
                    {"name":"Singing","description":"Singing","type":"checkbox","value":"Singing"},
                    {"name":"Sports","description":"Sports","type":"checkbox","value":"Sports"},
                    {"name":"Stunting","description":"Stunting","type":"checkbox","value":"Stunting"},
                    {"name":"Videography","description":"Checkthis","type":"checkbox","value":"Videography"},
                    {"name":"Other","description":"Other","type":"checkbox","value":"Other"},
                    {"name":"captcha"}
                    ]'
                    scrolling="auto"
                    frameborder="no"
                    style="border:none"
                    allowTransparency="true"
                    width="500"
                    height="800"

     >
            </iframe>
```

Comment: Is your JSON troncated ? The start and end are very strange.

Comment: then where am i going wrong if it's not valid @Residuum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace fields=[....] with valid JSON

```
[
{
    "name": "name"
},
{
    "name": "email"
},
{
    "name": "gender"
},
{
    "name": "birthday"
},
{
    "name": "captain",
    "description": "BestCaptain",
    "type": "select",
    "options": {
        "P": "Jean-LucPicard",
        "K": "JamesT.Kirk"
    }
},
{
    "name": "captain",
    "description": "College",
    "type": "select",
    "options": {
        "1": "Acropolis",
        "2": "Astral",
        "3": "Aurobindo",
        "4": "BM",
        "5": "Central",
        "6": "Chameli",
        "7": "IET(DAVV)",
        "8": "IIST",
        "9": "IIST2",
        "10": "IPS",
        "11": "JDCT",
        "12": "KCB",
        "13": "LKCT",
        "14": "LNCT",
        "15": "MIT(Malwa)",
        "16": "Malwa(Malwa2)",
        "17": "Mandsaur",
        "18": "Mathuradevi",
        "19": "MITM(Medi1)",
        "20": "MIST(Medi2)",
        "21": "MGIEM",
        "22": "Nalin",
        "23": "Oriental",
        "24": "Patel",
        "25": "Prestige",
        "26": "Priyatam",
        "27": "Rishiraj",
        "28": "RKDF",
        "29": "Royal",
        "30": "Sanghvi",
        "31": "Sdbansal",
        "32": "SGSITS",
        "33": "SIMS",
        "34": "SKSITS",
        "35": "Star",
        "36": "SVCE",
        "37": "SVITS",
        "38": "Transnational",
        "39": "Truba",
        "40": "Venkateshwar",
        "41": "Vidhyasagar",
        "42": "Vikrant",
        "43": "Vindhya",
        "44": "Acro",
        "45": "Apex",
        "46": "Arihant",
        "47": "BM",
        "48": "Chamelidevi",
        "49": "Chimc",
        "50": "Choithram",
        "51": "Christian",
        "52": "DCBS(DalyCollege)",
        "53": "IBMR",
        "54": "IIMR(IIST)",
        "55": "IIPS(DAVV)",
        "56": "Ilva",
        "57": "IMIR",
        "58": "Imperial",
        "59": "IMS(DAVV)",
        "60": "Islamia",
        "61": "JDCT",
        "62": "LKCT",
        "63": "LNCT",
        "64": "Maharaja",
        "65": "MIT(Malwa)",
        "66": "Mathuradevi",
        "67": "Matushri",
        "68": "MBKhalsa",
        "69": "Medicaps",
        "70": "Patel",
        "71": "Pioneer",
        "72": "Prestige",
        "73": "Priyatam",
        "74": "Renaissance",
        "75": "Rishiraj",
        "76": "Sahib",
        "77": "SAIMS",
        "78": "SanghviInnovative",
        "79": "Sapient",
        "80": "SGSITS",
        "81": "SIMS",
        "82": "SJDM",
        "83": "SKSITS",
        "84": "Softvision",
        "85": "SVCE",
        "86": "Rransnational",
        "87": "Vaishnav",
        "88": "Venkteshwar",
        "89": "Vidhyasagar",
        "90": "Vikrant",
        "91": "Acropolis",
        "92": "Aurobindo",
        "93": "BM",
        "94": "Central",
        "95": "SOPE(DAVV)",
        "96": "IIP(IIST)",
        "97": "IPS",
        "98": "Oriental",
        "99": "Rishiraj",
        "100": "RKDF",
        "101": "Safe",
        "102": "SGSITS",
        "103": "Smriti(SCOPE)",
        "104": "svce",
        "105": "vikrant",
        "106": "Arihant",
        "107": "BombayHospital",
        "108": "Index",
        "109": "MGMMC",
        "110": "RDMemorial",
        "111": "Shubhdeep",
        "112": "Aurobindo",
        "113": "CDSH",
        "114": "GCD",
        "115": "Index",
        "116": "Modern",
        "117": "BIGAims",
        "118": "Frameboxx",
        "119": "INIFD",
        "120": "MAAC",
        "121": "SDPS",
        "122": "SJMC(DAVV)",
        "123": "VirtualVoyage",
        "124": "Zica",
        "125": "IPS",
        "126": "SDPS",
        "127": "Christian",
        "128": "SOL(DAVV)",
        "129": "IIL",
        "130": "Vaishnav",
        "132": "EMRC(DAVV)",
        "P": "Jean-LucPicard",
        "K": "JamesT.Kirk",
        "#": "--------------------------------"
    }
},
{
    "name": "Arts",
    "description": "Arts",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Arts"
},
{
    "name": "Act",
    "description": "Act",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Act"
},
{
    "name": "Cooking",
    "description": "Cooking",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Cooking"
},
{
    "name": "Dance",
    "description": "Dance",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Dance"
},
{
    "name": "Designing",
    "description": "Designing",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Designing"
},
{
    "name": "Fashion",
    "description": "Fashion Designing",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Fashion Designing"
},
{
    "name": "Interior",
    "description": "Interior Designing",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Interior Designing"
},
{
    "name": "Modeling",
    "description": "Modeling",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Modeling"
},
{
    "name": "Photography",
    "description": "Photography",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Photography"
},
{
    "name": "Poetry",
    "description": "Poetry / Writing",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Poetry / Writing"
},
{
    "name": "Programming",
    "description": "Programming",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Programming"
},
{
    "name": "Reading",
    "description": "Reading",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Reading"
},
{
    "name": "Sketching",
    "description": "Sketching / Drawing",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Sketching / Drawing"
},
{
    "name": "Singing",
    "description": "Singing",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Singing"
},
{
    "name": "Sports",
    "description": "Sports",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Sports"
},
{
    "name": "Stunting",
    "description": "Stunting",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Stunting"
},
{
    "name": "Videography",
    "description": "Checkthis",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Videography"
},
{
    "name": "Other",
    "description": "Other",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": "Other"
},
{
    "name": "captcha"
}
]
```

Comment: I assume you just used `JSON.stringify` to build correct JSON and this removed most of the `'#':'Pharmacy'`/`'#':'Arts'`/etc lines. Just note (IMO they shouldn't be here anyway)

Comment: json should be placed inside "" so fields should looks like fields="[...]" . Problem is that you are trying to use iframe which does not allow you to have custom fields.

Comment: That worked, i guess there was a # field left in the select options which was generating the interrupt !

Answer (score 1):

Your `fields` parameter for Registration social plugin contain not valid JSON object (JSON should use double quotes instead of single quotes) and you're missing `,` (comma) in the middle of array, after next line:

```
{'name':'captain', 'description':'Best Captain', 'type':'select', 'options':{'P':'Jean-Luc Picard','K':'James T. Kirk'}}
```

**Update:**
Actually even usage of just valid JSON may not work in that case due to fact that this is passed as query string arguments, so that JSON should be properly encoded to avoid problems. Also may cause some issues.

Also you have two `fields` named "captain" (which cause problem with registration plugin too).

Here I've created some samples (due to massive code of fields, I'm not putting them here):

- Creating fields from JavaScript object and passing em to Registration plugin:  http://jsfiddle.net/QwdCv/
- Correctly encoded fields in URL passed directly within iframe tag src attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/QwdCv/1/

Comment: @user1216752, only adding the comma will not work, it's still not a valid JSON. and there is some more issues that I'll highlight soon.

Comment: That worked, i guess there was a # field left in the select options which was generating the interrupt !

Comment: @user1216752, look at the first sample I've provided, `#` doesn't caused any issue aside of being last option in one of selects. ;)